# Generate a specific number given X inputs of dice rolls

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dice

I'm trying to come up with a solution where I need to roll a number of dice (all of the same size) and come to a specified number. Provided I have all the validation in place to make sure the numbers are valid and could theoretically arrive at the desired result, does anyone have a good algorithm for solving this? Note it should appear random, not just a straight divide.

Some examples

> roll 3 d6 and get 14 -> so it could output 5,3,6 or 6,6,2
>
> roll 4 d20 and get 66 -> so it could output 16,14,19,17

I need a generic function that can accept a dice of any size, any amount to be rolled and the desired result.

My initial attempt is below, though this doesn't produce the desired output (you can ignore the `mod` for now, this was to also allow modifiers). This example is also missing the validation that the desired output is achievable,but that's not part of the question.

```
let desired = 19
let mod = 0
let dm = desired - mod
let n = 5;// number of dice
let d = 6 // dice sides
let nums = []

for(i =0; i< n; i++) {
    nums.push(Math.round(Math.random() * Math.round(d)) + 1)
}

let sum = nums.reduce((acc,val) => acc + val)


nums = nums.map(a => Math.round((a/sum) * dm))

let diff = dm - (nums.reduce((acc,val) => acc + val))
function recursive(diff) {
    let ran = nums[Math.random() * Math.round(nums.length -1)]
    if(nums[ran] + diff > d || nums[ran] + diff < 1) {
        recursive(diff)
    } else {
        nums[ran] += diff
    }
}
while(diff != 0) {
    recursive(diff)
    diff += diff < 0 ? 1 : -1;
}

alert(nums)
```

Comment: You just need one valid set of rolls for each target?

Comment: Yes, I imagine the function signature would be something along the lines of :

`function generateRolls(desiredResult, numberOfDiceToRoll, numberOfDiceSides)`

I'd like them to look random though, so not just a case of divide the result by the numberOfDice

Comment: Ok so you work backwards from the requirement that you have enough range on the last roll to get to zero, counting down from the target. This it to avoid needing 8 when you have a D6 for example.

Comment: Can you expand on this a bit more? Make an answer maybe?

Comment: Do you really only need one "random-looking" partition, or will you call the function repeatedly with the same parameters? You can get uniformly-distributed solutions if it is possible to do some precomputation, but that's a lot of work for a single solution.

Comment: @rici well it will be called more than once, but not necessarily a lot or in quick succession

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soluton in ruby:

```
def foo(count, dim, desired, results = [])
  return results if count == 0
  raise ArgumentError if count > desired
  raise ArgumentError if count * dim < desired

  max_roll = (dim <= desired - count) ? dim : desired - count + 1
  min_roll = [(desired - (count-1) * dim), 1].max
  roll = (rand(min_roll..max_roll))
  results << roll

  foo(count - 1, dim, desired - roll, results)

  results
end

puts foo(3, 6, 11).inspect
puts foo(2, 6, 11).inspect
puts foo(4, 4, 11).inspect
```

Results:

```
[3, 4, 4]
[5, 6]
[2, 3, 4, 2]
```

So basically it is recursive function. For each step:

- roll a dice (within allowed range min_roll..max_roll)
- call same function but reduce count by already consumed number by dice and extend results array by value of roll

Note one thing: with this behaviour you may have larger numbers in the beginning of result. To avoid this just shuffle result of function in the end of it

Comment: Setting min_roll to the ratio `desired / count` seems to *guarantee* that the beginning of the result will not have small numbers. It's impossible to start with a roll of 1, for example, unless desired is less than twice the number of dice.

Comment: my bad! fixed - this was just to prevent situations when in 2k6 first dices gives 1 so second throw is impossible

Answer (score 2):

recursive:

```js
function foo(desired, rolls, sides, current) {
  if (rolls === 0) {
    return current.reduce((s, c) => s + c) === desired ? current : null;
  }
  
  const random = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= sides; i++) {
    const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (random.length + 1))
    random.splice(randomIndex, 0, i);
  }
  
  for (const n of random) {
    const result = foo(desired, rolls - 1, sides, [...current, n]);
    if (result) {
      return result;
    }
  }
}

console.log(foo(14, 3, 6, []))
```

non-recursive:

```js
function foo(desired, rolls, sides) {
  const stack = [[]];
  while (stack.length) {
    const current = stack.pop();    
    const random = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= sides; i++) {
      const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (random.length + 1));
      random.splice(randomIndex, 0, i);
    }
  
    for (const n of random) {
      if (current.length === rolls - 1) {
        if (current.reduce((s, c) => s + c + n) === desired) {
          return [...current, n];
        }
      } else {
        stack.push([...current, n]);
      }
    }
  }   
}

console.log(foo(14, 3, 6));
```

non-recursive with minimum memory consumption:

```js
function foo(desired, rolls, sides) {
  const currentIndexes = Array(rolls).fill(0);
  const randoms = Array.from({ length: rolls }, () => {
    const random = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= sides; i++) {
      const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (random.length + 1));
      random.splice(randomIndex, 0, i);
    }
    return random;
  })
  while (true) {
    if (currentIndexes.reduce((s, idx, i) => s + randoms[i][idx], 0) === desired) {
      return currentIndexes.map((idx, i) => randoms[i][idx]);
    }
    for (let i = currentIndexes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (currentIndexes[i] < sides - 1) {
        currentIndexes[i] += 1;
        break;
      }
      currentIndexes[i] = 0;
    }
  }
}

console.log(foo(14, 3, 6));
```

non-recursive solution with minimum memory consumption and increased performance by calculating the last roll based on previous rolls.

```js
function foo(desired, rolls, sides) {
  const currentIndexes = Array(rolls - 1).fill(0);
  const randoms = Array.from({ length: rolls - 1 }, () => {
    const random = [];
    for (let i = 1; i <= sides; i++) {
      const randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (random.length + 1));
      random.splice(randomIndex, 0, i);
    }
    return random;
  })
  while (true) {
    const diff = desired - currentIndexes.reduce((s, idx, i) => s + randoms[i][idx], 0);
    if (diff > 0 && diff <= sides) {
      return [...currentIndexes.map((idx, i) => randoms[i][idx]), diff];
    }
    for (let i = currentIndexes.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (currentIndexes[i] < sides - 1) {
        currentIndexes[i] += 1;
        break;
      }
      currentIndexes[i] = 0;
    }
  }
}

console.log(foo(66, 4, 20));
```

Comment: The second solution doesn't seem to work. Eg. `console.log(foo(60, 10, 10, []))` => `[ 5, 4, 10, 2, 2, 6, 9, 5, 9, 1 ]` which sums to 53, not 60. The other ones seem to work (at least on a few trials), but don't look very random to me.

Comment: I have to agree, there doesn't seem to be a lot of randomness. For instance if I just roll 2 dice, it always gives the same result every time 

`console.log(foo(18, 2, 20, []))` always outputs

`17,1`

And that's using the non-recursive functions as well

Comment: @TommyBs whoops, I forgot parens enclosing `random.length + 1` which had made `1` always the first rolled number. Sorry for that. Now it should be ok.

Comment: Thanks I've +1, appreciate you wrote your answers in JS as I asked, but I've accepted the ruby answer below. Purely as it came first and helped me work through the problem myself